# Harry Potter fan fiction where Harry is pulled back into the time of the founders

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

There is a fanfic I'm looking for where Harry is pulled back into the time of the founders by Gryffindor's magic after he is tortured by Voldemort. The founders then train him and he becomes a phoenix animagius and a fire elementalist. He saves the kings life and is knighted. Everyone thinks he is dead. He returns and Dumbledore tries to expel him but can't because he can't change a founder decree. Harry also finds the key to the house of Evans's vault. He dosen't have any siblings. He also makes his own sword. PostGof PreOotP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for Harry Potter fanfic where he travels back to founders era, is trained by all four founders, is a fire elemental and a phoenix animagus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187059/looking-for-harry-potter-fanfic-where-he-travels-back-to-founders-era-is-traine)

Comment: @jwodder we don't close until there's an acceptance, whether it be a checkmark or a comment, but it sounds very dupey indeed. LegoLover, can you confirm (or deny) that it is _Twins a Different Life_? :)

Comment: On top of that, there is no acceptance in the dupe-target, so this question should not be closed anyways. (But it's always good to link the two)

Comment: The story I'm looking for Isn't Twins a Different Life. I looked at it but it isn't what I'm looking for

Comment: Do you remember what site you read it on?

Answer (score 4):

### [*Twins: A Different Life*](http://rereadfanfiction.blogspot.com/2014/05/twins-different-life-gen.html?m=1) by Jessiikaa15

> Harry is banished to the Dursleys. Merlin steps in and transports Harry back to the time of the founders. Yes this is cliche but really there are only so many ideas but the author knows this and does not spend a lot of time there. Instead we meet a confident, cunning, ambitious founders heir who is determined to teach his birth parents and Dumbledore a lesson.

Also answered over [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/188530/58193).

Comment: He doesn't have a sister